# Find the infamous element in the array

Tags: javascript

I want to find the infamous element in the array using javascript. 
I've found the most common element, now I need to find the infamous element of an array.
  array: `[4,4,4,4,1,4,4]`

any ideas?

Comment: By "infamous", do you mean the only element that occurs a single time? (That's not what "infamous" means.) What if the array was `[4,4,4,2,4,1,4]` - would your expected result be `2` or `1`, or `[2,1]`, or...?

Comment: yes, I mean the one that occurs a single time. if there are more than one, it should return the first element. any ideas?

Comment: I guess you're looking for "infrequent", not "infamous". So you need to count how many time each occurs, get the lowest frequency, then the first that occurs that many times. I think there are answers here already to do all of that.

Comment: *"I've found the most common element"* - How did you do that? The "normal" procedure would be to iterate over the array using a working object to keep count of how many times each value appears, so if you did that the same code could find both the most common and least common.

Comment: I've found using two loop. here is my code:

Comment: function aLaMode(array){
 var count = 1;
 var m = 0;
 var item = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
      for (var j = i; j < array.length; j++)
      {
          if (array[i] == array[j])
          {
           m = m + 1;
        if (count < m)
        {
            count = m; 
            item = array[i];
        }
         } 
      }
      m = 0;
  }
  return item;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by iterating over the array and count the number of times each element occurs. Since you want the first instance of the least common value, you'll also need to store the index the first time the value occurs since you can't depend on the order they're inserted into the object as objects aren't ordered.

Then find the least common value with the lowest index, e.g.

```js
var data = [4,4,4,4,1,4,4,2,4,4];

var values = data.reduce(function (acc, value, i) {
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
    acc[value] = {count: 0, index: i};
  }
  acc[value].count++;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log('Collated values:\n' + JSON.stringify(values));

var result = Object.keys(values).reduce(function(acc, value) {
  var obj = values[value];
  if (obj.count <= acc.count && obj.index < acc.index ) {
    acc = {value: value, count: obj.count, index: obj.index};
  }
  return acc;
}, {value: null, count: Infinity, index: Infinity});

console.log('Result:\n' + JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that finds out the famous and infamous elements of an array -

```js
var mainArr = [4,4,4,4,1,4,4];
var ele = [], occ = [];
var str = "";
for(var index,count=0;count<mainArr.length;count++){
 index = ele.indexOf(mainArr[count]);
 if(index > -1){
     occ[index]++;
    }else{
     ele.push(mainArr[count]);
        occ.push(1);
    }
}
console.log("Infamous : "+ele[occ.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, occ))]);
console.log("Famous : "+ele[occ.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, occ))]);
```